# Plot specified points first then data from file using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot data from two sources: (1) specific points that define a diagonal from (0, 0) to (1, 1), and (2) file containing my analyzed data. Currently, I can do this using the following command:

```
plot [0:1][0:1] 'sample.dat' using 1:2 with lines,\
'-' title 'random AUC=0.50' with lines dashtype 2
0 0
0 0
0.5 0.5
1 1
e
```

which outputs the following:

[image: sample AUC plot]

However, I want the diagonal line to appear first. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot the diagonal, simply plot the function `x`.

**Code:**

```
### plot order
reset session

set size square
set xrange[0:1]
set yrange[0:1]

# create some test data
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(int($1*10+1.5)/10.) w table
unset table

set key top left

plot x with lines dt 2 title 'random AUC=0.50', \
    $Data u 1:2 w l ti 'sample AUC=0.596'
### end of code
```

**Addition:**

If you want to plot arbitrary points instead of `x`:

```
$myPoints <<EOD
0    0
0.1  0.2
0.5  0.7
1.0  1.0
EOD

plot $myPoints u 1:2 w lines
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Plotting f(x) works for my case. However, is there a more general solution to plot points then file(s)?

Comment: Late comment, but the addendum is just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The elements of a 2D plots are always drawn in the order you give them, so
`plot A,B` will draw `A` first, and `plot B,A` will draw `B` first.